# What is the metaphorical meaning of "olla podriga" in this context?

Tags: metaphors

What is the metaphorical meaning of "olla podriga" in this context?

> Civilisation and barbarism, crudity and culture, the latter depending
>   on the European occupant individually, for collectively culture is
>   conspicuous by its absence in Ceylon—ancient and modern, everything
>   antithetical and anachronal arranged together in a delightful ***olla
>   podriga*** of the Orient and the Occident.
>
> - Ceylon : The Paradise of Adam - by Caroline Corner - 1908 - pg 7

Edit: According to comments, I guess, as the authoress is a British author, she had misspelled the spanish word "olla podrida", the spanish dish.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you looked up the words? Having discovered the probable mis-spelling, is there any reason that the metaphorical meaning would be anything other than the obvious one?

Comment: If the context is talking about 'olla podrida', the spanish dish, still I don't have the idea. Never saw or eaten a one. Just heard today.

Comment: Hodge-podge is how I'd interpret this without using a dictionary, which is what it does mean regardless of the dish.

Comment: fantastic replacement term, @xanne !!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 'Olla Podrida' has two meanings:

> 1. a spicy Spanish stew of sausage and other meat, chickpeas, and often tomatoes and other vegetables.
> 2. an incongruous mixture or miscellany

Metaphorically, therefore, it implies that:

> Civilisation and barbarism, crudity and culture, the latter depending on the European occupant individually, for collectively culture is conspicuous by its absence in Ceylon—ancient and modern, everything antithetical and anachronal arranged together in a **delightfully incongruous mixture** of the Orient and the Occident.

**The implication is that none of the above list really links, and is comparable to a soup made of many ingredients.**

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com/browse/olla%20podrida)